# Infimum of an even degree polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, maxima-minima

I need to prove that every even degree polynomial function such that its higher-degree coefficient is positive reaches its infimum.I have it more or less proved, but there are some things that worry me. Let $p(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$, being $n$ even and $a_n>0$:

1. As $\lim_{x\to-\infty} p'(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}p'(x)=\infty$ and p'(x) is continuous; can I just say $p(x)$ has at least a relative minimum or do I have to prove something more?
2. How can I prove the lowest relative minimum of $p(x)$ is necessarily an absolute minimum? It seems obvious but I can´t think of a formal proof. I know both limits of p(x) in infinity are $\infty$, but I'm not able to apply this information to this concrete purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know there is a lowest relative minimum?

Comment: Well, there can only be a finite number of relative minima ( n-1 in this case) and we know there's at least one ( because of the limits of the derivative). Then, we can take the minimum of the set formed by this minima, which will be the lowest relative minimum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I don't see why you want to prove the existence of a relative minimum. What you're after is an absolute minimum.
2. Since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}p(x)=+\infty$, there's a $M>0$ such that $|x|>M\implies p(x)>p(0)$. And since the interval $[-M,M]$ is closed and bounded, there's a $x_0\in[-M,M]$ such that$$\bigl(\forall x\in[M,M]\bigr):p(x_0)\leqslant p(x).$$So, $p$ reaches its absolute minimum at $x_0$, since outside $[-M,M]$ you have $p(x)\geqslant p(0)\geqslant p(x_0)$.

Comment: Thank you. I have just realized I was making things much more difficult than they were

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} p(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty} p(x)=\infty.
$$

Step 2. Hence, there exists an $M>0$, such that
$$
|x|>M\quad\Longrightarrow\quad p(x)>p(0).
$$ 
Step 3. Thus
$$
\inf_{x\in\mathbb R}p(x)=\inf_{x\in[-M,m]}p(x)
$$

Step 4. But
$$
\inf_{x\in[-M,m]}p(x)=\min_{x\in [-M,M]}p(x),
$$
since continuous functions in $[-M,M]$ assume their extrema.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the second information, namely that $p(x)\rightarrow \infty$, when $\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty$. Take $C>0$ such that  $K=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\vert p(x) \le C\}$ is nonempty. $K$ is closed and it is bounded (because otherwise you would have a sequence $\vert x_n \vert \rightarrow \infty$, with $p(x_n)$ bounded by $C$, a contradiction), hence $K$ is compact and $p$, being continuous, achieves its minimum at some $x_0 \in K$. This automatically is a global minimum, as for any $x \notin K$  we have $p(x_0) \le C < p(x).$

Answer (score 1):

.All you need to prove is that any such polynomial reaches its infimum. That is, there is a point $a \in \Bbb R$ such that $p(a) = \displaystyle\inf_{x \in \Bbb R} p(x)$.

First, we must prove that the infimum exists. Then, we must show that at some point $a$ the infimum is attained.

Now, what we do know is that $\lim_{x \to \infty} p(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} p(x) = \infty$. In particular, there exists $R > 0$ such that $|x| > R \implies p(x) > 5000$, by the definition of the limit being infinite in both directions.

Next, note that $p(x)$ is continuous on $[-R,R]$, so  $p(x)$ attains a minimum on $[-R,R]$, call it $m$. Note that $p(x) \geq \min\{5000,m\}$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. In particular, the set $\{p(x) : x \in \mathbb R\}$ has a lower bound. By the greatest lower bound property, $\inf_{x \in \mathbb R} p(x)$ exists. Let's call it $L$.

By the limit property, there exists $R' > 0$ such that if $|x| > R'$ then $|p(x)| > L + 5000$. Let us focus on $p$ in the interval $[-R',R']$ now.

We claim that $\inf_{x \in [-R',R']} p(x) = L$. To see this, note that $L$ is the infimum of $p(x)$ over a larger interval, so $\geq$ follows. For the other direction, if $5000 > \epsilon > 0$, then there exists some $x \in \Bbb R$ such that $|f(x)| < L + \epsilon$. But then, from how $R'$ is defined, we know that such an $x$ can only lie in $[-R',R']$. So there is $x \in [-R',R']$ such that $f(x) > L + \epsilon$. Now, the inequality follows.

Finally, of course on compact sets ,infimums of continuous functions are attained, so there exists $a \in [-R',R']$ so that $p(a) = L = \inf_{x \in \Bbb R} p(x)$, completing the proof.

Key points of the proof:

- $\inf_{x \in \Bbb R} p(x)$ exists because we have $p(x)$ increasing to infinity uniformly on both sides, so we can cut $p(x)$ off after some time to get a compact set on which everything works out.
- Once the infimum is there, we cut off $p(x)$ at a *point after which we know that the infimum won't surely be attained* (hence distinguishing it from the first cutoff) and then use compactness.